# ArrayList retrieving value of object

Tags: c#, arraylist

This is getting made in a static void method in the main class. (class being used for input).

```
private static void Input(ArrayList list)
{
   //other code...

   Object b = new Object(number, hour, minutes, seconds);
   list.Add(b)
}
```

Next I have another static void method to display the objects within.
The thing is i want to group them on the number, and then display all the hours, minutes and seconds for the same number underneath each other.
Then the following number(s) with all there corresponding hours, minutes and seconds.

But I am not sure how i can get the number for example the first array, and 2nd and so on.

How can I access this? The syntax below does not work and not sure how to retrieve this value(s).

```
int var = array[0].number; //does not work
```

Also how do i make a instance of this object again? I cannot use new again can i?

```
 private static void Output(ArrayList list)
{
   while (i < list.Count)
   {
      //keep track of current group (number)
      //announce group
      //...
   }
}
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you're using a non-generic collection (`ArrayList` instead of `List<T>`). If you can, it would be *much* better to use a generic collection. However, if you're forced to use `ArrayList`, you've got to cast:

```
Foo foo = (Foo) list[0];
int x = foo.number;
...
```

(I hope you haven't *really* named your own class `Object`... I would also recommend against using the name `var` as that is a contextual keyword as of C# 3.)

Comment: The names are indeed only for illustration. Will try with the casting and afterwards make it with a generic class. Cheers for the input.

Comment: @Tonz: In future, it's worth using names which *aren't* part of the standard library.

Comment: Will do, although i still cannot acces the number itself?

Comment: @Tonz: Well you should be able to, after casting... assuming `number` is an accessible member of the type you've cast to. Without a complete example, it's hard to know what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an `ArrayList`, use a `List<T>` where `T` is your type of object.